# while posting json to webapi error occured : Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: json, cross-domain, azure-storage

Am trying to post json data to the server. am using visual studio 2012 RC and windowsazure for hosting the web application  . On posting am getting the following errors :

1. OPTIONS http://***.azurewebsites.net/api/Child 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.7.1.js:8102
2. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://***.azurewebsites.net/api/Child. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My client side code is :

```
       function PostChild() {                  
        var Chld = {};            
        Chld.Child_FirstName = $("#Child_FirstName").val();
        Chld.Child_LastName = $("#Child_LastName").val();
        Chld.Child_Age = $("#Child_Age").val();          
        var createurl = "http://*.azurewebsites.net/api/Child";                      
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: createurl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(Chld),       
            statusCode: {
                200: function () {
                    $("#txtmsg").val("done");
                    alert('Success');
                }
            },
            error:
                function (res) {
                    alert('Error');
                    $("#txtmsg").val("error" + " "
                    + res.status + " " + res.statusText);
                }
        });
    }
```

My server side code is :

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostChild(Child child)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Children.Add(child);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, child);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = child.ChildID }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Help me please

Thanks,

Comment: Is the web page being served up by the same domain as the web API? (*.azurewebsites.net, which I assume means <something>.azurewebsites.net and not literally an asterisk)

Comment: @smarx ofcouse, it is not an asterisk. It is domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors was due to CORS (Cross Origin Resource sharing). By default, a web page cannot make calls to services (APIs) on a domain other than the one where the page came from. This is a security measure to avoid cross-site forgery attacks and all.

To solve it follow this tutorial:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx

Comment: So I guess the answer to my question was "no."

Comment: @smarx yes, webpage is served from different domain